# XML validation with xsd as Source

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I want to validate my xml with xsd sxheme. When I load xsd as new File() - al is ok.
But I can't do this 'xos of .jar. So i use this code to load xsd

```
public static boolean init() {
    try (InputStream isSchema = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(XSD_PATH)) {
        System.out.println(getStringFromInputStream(isSchema));
        schemaSource = new StreamSource(isSchema);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.debug(e.toString());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

isScheme object has valid content of .xsd file. But when I call it

```
    private boolean validateXML(File xmlFile) {
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile)) {
        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(stream);
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
            .newSchema(schemaSource)
            .newValidator()
            .validate(xmlSource);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("ERROR XML parsing for [" + xmlFile.getName() + "] : " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

An error occurs

> DEBUG Task:82 - ERROR XML parsing for [test good 4 - копия - копия (380) - копия - копия - копия - копия - копия - копия.xml] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

This is my XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Entry">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="content">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="1024" />
                        <xs:minLength value="0" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="creationDate">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:length value="19" />
                        <xs:pattern value="[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"></xs:pattern>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Example of xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Entry>
    <content>any message</content>
    <creationDate>2016-06-15 20:20:20</creationDate>
  </Entry>
```

Help me please.

I change mu code to this

```
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile)) {
        isSchema = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(XSD_PATH);
        schemaSource = new StreamSource(isSchema);
        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(stream);
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
            .newSchema(schemaSource)
            .newValidator()
            .validate(xmlSource);
    }
```

and to this

```
try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile)) {
        InputStream isSchema = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(XSD_PATH);
        Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(isSchema);
        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(stream);
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
            .newSchema(schemaSource)
            .newValidator()
            .validate(xmlSource);
    }
```

But the same error.

Comment: Name of file `test good 4 - копия - копия (380) - копия - копия - копия - копия - копия - копия.xml` is so weird

Comment: check existence of resource in your xsd path XSD_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of StreamSource [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.java#StreamSource.setInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29):

The StreamSource constructor which takes InputStream merely calls the setter. So the underlying inputstream must be kept open to be able to read from the streamSource.

When the `try` within your `init()` completes, it closes the inputstream, so I the streamsource instance (`schemaSource`) becomes useless at that point. You will have to open the schema file at the time of validating the XML.

Comment: @R1K0 Is it exactly the same error? Do you get it for XSD again or the XML file? If it is still for the XSD, your XSD path is wrong. `getResourceAsStream()` returns null if resource is not found.

Comment: No. The problem in xsd file. "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>." But printing xsd shows normal content

Comment: @R1K0 Right, then as I said, your XSD_PATH does not contain the XSD file. That's why it is null.

Comment: So why when I create InputStream from XSD file with XSD_PATH - it contains all from this file ?

Comment: "it contains all from this file" - Do you say that because in `init`, your `getStringFromInputStream()` call prints the XSD contents? If so, then the only reason I can think of is you're calling `init` from a different thread whose classloader does have access to the XSD.